# WHERE Clause to get month and year from current date in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to filter data by month and also year from sql database. I set my current date to (yyyy-MM-dd) format. From there i want to filter by month and year. Below is my source code.

```
     Dim ServerDate As String
        ServerDate = Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        Dim nowYear As Integer
        nowYear = Date.Now.Year
        Dim nowMonth As Integer
        nowMonth = Date.Now.Month
```

This one my select statement:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "Select COUNT(*) FROM ScanningData WHERE ASSET_NUMBER=" & AssetTxt.Text & " And LOC_DEPT=" & DeptCodeTxt.Text & " AND UNIT_NO=" & UnitNoTxt.Text & " AND UPDATE_DATE='" & nowMonth & nowYear & "';"
```

Can someone help me on this. Thank you in advance

Comment: do you want create a sql query where it will return records of specific month and year only?

Comment: @Sreenath Ganga actually i want to filter data which mean if month and year are in the same day the record just update, if not, need to save to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DATEPART

Eg(not tested for syntax error)

```
Select COUNT(*) FROM ScanningData 
WHERE ASSET_NUMBER=" & AssetTxt.Text & " And LOC_DEPT=" & DeptCodeTxt.Text & " 
AND UNIT_NO=" & UnitNoTxt.Text & " AND ( DATEPART(mm, CreationDate) = "& nowMonth & ") and (DATEPART(yy, CreationDate)="& nowYear  & " )
```

Comment: @hasni does it help you